# That Operator || in console.log() works like || operator?

Tags: javascript

How it's work for example;

```
let x;
console.log(x || 2); // 2
```

if

```
let x = 4;
console.log(x || 2); // 4
```

if

```
let x = 5;
let y = 7;
console.log( y || x || 2);
```

it's mean that console.log() write first value that is true ?

Comment: No, it's how `||` works.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: It has nothing to do with `console.log()`. The `||` operator simply returns the value of the left operand if it's truthy and the value of the right operand otherwise. `console.log()` simply receives and logs the returned value.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that the correct duplication target since the misunderstanding is over short circuiting, not if `0 == false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing isn't related to `console.log`. It's called [short circuiting.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)

When comparing values with `||`, it will always return the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. If no truthy values are present, it will return the last value being compared.

```js
let a = false || true;
let b = false || null || 'b';
let c = undefined || !a || 10;
let d = undefined || false || null; // no truthy values

console.log(a); // true
console.log(b); // 'b'
console.log(c); // 10
console.log(d); // null
```

Comment: It returns the first truthy value if the first value is truthy. If the first isn't, then it returns the second value no matter if it truthy or not.

Comment: @Quentin Very true. Better clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
let x = 5;
let y = 7;
console.log( y || x || 2); //return 7
```

`expr1 || expr2`    Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators